# Invalid comparison of complex

Tags: python, arrays, comparison, complex-numbers

I have an array of length 3 made by the program, named `fp`. Printing `fp` gives me:

```
[79.7298483050264 71.030916539624 - 67.1485131001781*I
 71.030916539624 + 67.1485131001781*I]
```

I want to determine the max element of this array (in real part). So I use:
 `print max(fp.real)`

But the program gives me this error:

```
"Invalid comparison of complex %s" % me
```

I don't know what the problem is. I am sure the type of `fp` is an array.

---

I checked again. the problem is that fp.real does not work.  the output of fp.real is the same as fp, which contains complex numbers.

but for an input array, named a=[1+2j,2+3j], the a.real works properly.

I am totally confused!

---

for more information: 
fp is fixed points of a function:
fp=solve(func3(x,popt3[0],popt3[1],popt3[2],popt3[3]),x)

which is a list. then I convert it to an array.

Comment: Is fp.real a string?

Comment: @MysticForce type of fp is 'numpy.ndarray', so the type of fp.real is also an array.  (I checked it)